# How to call a method in an activity from onLocationChanged() of another class

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I know how to call methods from other classes, but it doesn't seem to work in this case. I may be mistaken but I tried several things, none worked. Here is the related, simplified code:

MainActivity.java :

```
private void getForecast(final GPSTracker gpsTracker) {
             // something
}
```

GPSTracker.java :

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // call getForecast() here
}
```

What I basically want to do is to get forecast data once the user enables location. Right now, on start app detects that location is disabled, directs user to Settings to enable it, but after user enables it and comes back to the app, nothing changes. App does not understand that location is changed, so I'm assuming that onLocationChanged() is the way to go. I can provide the rest of the code if needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need pay attention on [Access Modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) of getForecast method. You can't call getForecast() from another java class.

**Edited:**
You need to change access modifier from private to public:

```
public void getForecast(final GPSTracker gpsTracker) {
             // something
}
```

Also make sure that you call function [requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

Comment: Yeah I've seen that thread, but there is no actual answer there so it does not solve my problem. It'S the first time I'm hearing about Access Modifier. I'll read that documentation, but in the mean time, is there any way I can call that method? I mean, there must be SOME way, right? @Andrew M.

Comment: @OnurÇevik Yes, you have to change access modifier from private to public. After you'll read official documentation, you know what modifier best in your case.